# Error while importing component from library

Tags: reactjs, next.js, rollup, headless-ui, tsdx

I'm working on this component library that uses `tsdx`, all of the components work fine except for this one. It's a dialog that uses the `@headlessui/react` lib, and it's `Dialog` component. It's exported like this:

```
DialogBase.Content = DialogContent;
DialogBase.Actions = DialogActions;
DialogBase.Description = DialogDescription;

export default DialogBase;
```

Then, in the `index.ts` file, where I have to export all my components to expose them, it's exported like this:

```
export { default as DialogBase } from './DialogBase';
```

Everything works fine, but when I try to use the component on a different project I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "Overlay", u.Dialog is undefined

And it's weird because the component works fine on other Nextjs projects, but not on this one (this one is CRA).

This is my `tsconfig` file

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.extend.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "ESNext",
    "target": "esnext",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "./../src",
    "rootDir": "./",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "types": ["node", "jest", "@testing-library/jest-dom", "facebook-js-sdk"],
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

and my `tsconfig.extend` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "@test/*": ["./__test__/*"],
      "@components/*": ["./components/*"],
      "@domain/*": ["./domain/*"],
      "@hooks/*": ["./hooks/*"],
      "@context/*": ["./context/*"],
      "@pages/*": ["./pages/*"],
      "@services/*": ["./services/*"],
      "@types/*": ["./types/*"],
      "@util/*": ["./util/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

As sugested by one of the answers I removed the `Overlay` component, now I'm getting this error:

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

I also have to mention that other components exported the same way are working fine on both apps.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some reason downgrading @headlessui to 1.4 (I was using 1.7) works.

Answer (score 4):

On surfing through their [docs](https://headlessui.com/react/dialog#dialog-overlay), It says `Dialog.Overlay` is deprecated from `v1.6` (Released 25 Apr 2022). As you said it works on other Next.js projects but not in the new CRA, May be the component you built uses this old `Dialog.Overlay`. If it does, then use the migration guide from the [Release Notes](https://github.com/tailwindlabs/headlessui/releases/tag/%40headlessui%2Freact%40v1.6.0).

Comment: I also tried that but no luck.

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It's not a pretty solution, but if it works, you can at least be pretty certain that the issue is with transpiling and if so, then your preferred syntax may work with the help of a Babel plugin.

```js
import DialogBase from './DialogBase';
export { DialogBase }
```

If it doesn't work, then your issue is presumably TypeScript-specific.

Comment: Tried changing the export and it didn't work, also tried to use the same ts-config as in the other projects and didn't work either.